# Python - Extract Number From String Without Square Bracket

Tags: python

So i am currently developing an AI, but i need help with getting the age. So if someone inputs "I am 14 years old" i want it to take the 14 and set it has a variable. I have done this but, square brackets go around the output, which i don't want, so i am looking for a way to,get the number from the string without square brackets.
This is my code

```
#Gets users age
elif "i am" in inp and "years old" in inp:
  age=[int(s) for s in inp.split() if s.isdigit()]
  age=str(age)
  print(age)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You are casting a list to string, why not access to the element first ? `age = str(age[0])`

Comment: It's because `age` was a list. To get the first number use `str(age[0])` (you will get an indexerror if the input did not include a number.)

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex:

```
import re
m = re.search("\d+", "I am 14 years old")
if m:
    print(int(m.group()))
```

**Output:**

```
14
```

Comment: I also tried this and it also worked so thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
age=[s for s in inp.split() if s.isdigit()]
int(''.join([str(s) for s in age]))
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using your method:**

Simply use a less "compact" syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

inp="i am 15 years old"

#Gets users age
if "i am" in inp and "years old" in inp:
    for s in inp.split():
      if s.isdigit():
        age=int(s)
    print(age)
```

Running this code give:

```
$ python pouet.py 
15
```

**2. Using regular expressions**

Regular expressions are more adapted to such a task.
The code below parses the age of the user even if he's 1 year (with no 's') old or if he abbreviates "i am" to "i'm":

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

test_v=[ "i am 15 years old", "i'm 1 year old"]

#Gets users age
for test_string in test_v:
    res = re.match('(i am|i\'m) (\d+) year[s]? old', test_string)
    if (res):
        print res.group(2)
```

Running this code give:

```
$ python pouet.py 
15
1
```

Comment: I am going to use this way, over the others, as i found the others had brackets around them. So thanks so much.